# angular route linking code but code isn't working

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm relatively new to angular, I can't seem to understand why my code is not working, the part home is put inside the home.html file which I loaded inside from the ng-route. The function seems to be working fine but when I try to put the code variable inside the html file, the variable doesn't show up.

However when I put whole code inside the main html file and execute the same function the program prints out the variable just fine. 
Can someone please help me?

## Unit information System

```
<!--home.html-->
<div ng-controller="More_info">
<div data-ng-init = "unitObj=
                    [{code:'ICT10001', desc:'Problem Solving with ICT', cp:12.5, type:'Core'},
                    {code:'COS10005', desc:'Web Development', cp:12.5, type:'Core'},
                    {code:'INF10003', desc:'Introduction to Business Information Systems', cp:12.5, type:'Core'},
                    {code:'INF10002', desc:'Database Analysis and Design', cp:12.5, type:'Core'},
                    {code:'COS10009', desc:'Introduction to Programming', cp:12.5, type:'Core'},
                    {code:'INF30029', desc:'Information Technology Project Management', cp:12.5, type:'Core'},
                    {code:'ICT30005', desc:'Professional Issues in Information Technology', cp:12.5, type:'Core'},
                    {code:'ICT30001', desc:'Information Technology Project', cp:12.5, type:'Core'}] ">

                <!--    <div data-ng-repeat="x in unitObj||"x">
                        <p data-ng-show="inputStr==x.code">{{x.desc}}</p>
                        <p data-ng-show="descStr==x.desc">-->
                <table class = "table table-striped">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Code</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>More info</th>
                    </tr>

                    <tr ng-repeat = "x in unitObj|filter:filterObj">

                        <td>{{x.code}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.desc}}</td>
                        <td><a href ="#" ng-click="more_info(x);">show details</a></td>

                    </tr>

                </table>

    </div>
    {{Code}}
</div>
```

Angular part of the file

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/home',{
        templateUrl:'view/home.html',
        controller:'More_info'
    })
        .when('/directory',{
          templateUrl:'view/directory.html',
          controller:'Contorol'
          })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo:'/home'
    })
}]);

app.controller("More_info", function($scope)
{
    $scope.more_info = function(x)
    {
        alert("This is working!")
        $scope.Code=x.code;
        $scope.Desc=x.desc;
        $scope.Credit =x.cp;
        $scope.Type = x.type;
    }

}
              );
```

HTML main file

```
<body class ="container">
   <ul style ="list-style-type:none; ">
        <li style ="display:inline"><a href="#!/home">Home</a></li>
       <li style ="display:inline"><a href = "#!/directory">Directory</a></li>

    </ul>

    <main ng-view>  

    </main>
```

Comment: put your code on plunkr

Comment: Why do you use ng-init? Is this just for the example and you will get this information from the backend inside the HTML like '<div data-ng-init = "unitObj=<?php echo $array/>"> </div>? If you don't get this data from the backend don't use ng-init

Comment: Hey Mr Wook. I can access the data inside unitObj from the js file.

Comment: Like i said don't use "ng-init" it should only be used in special cases for ng-repeat or to inject server side data. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit 
You can initialize the array in the controller with $scope.unitObj=[...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure about `templteUrl` directories in route configuration in app.config then issue will be resolved automatically.

Update:
When using `a` tag without routing purpose, use `href` without any string passing to it. So use it like:

`<a href="" ng-click="clickFunc()">Click</a>` OR

`<a href ng-click="clickFunc()">Click</a>` OR Even better:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="clickFunc()">Click</a>
```

(Actually for such purposes you can just use span/buttons with any needed styles)

**[Working Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/u97vKBzZh2YPDN5pEuiE?p=preview)**

Comment: Hey Shantanu, 
The purpose of main tag is the same as a div tag, could you please elaborate in the template Url part?q

Comment: @BinayDhawa Follow the plunker example I’ve created using your code. I was saying just make sure the directory of partial views is correct in templateUrl part of route config.

Comment: Hey Shantanu, the config works fine in my code. The isuue is that on home.html the code portion isnt showing up in the view. I want to be able to view the code when i click on show details.

Comment: @BinayDhawa Check updated answer. In angularjs href actually overrides ng-click so just use it without passing any url string to it. See updated plunker example.

Comment: @Shantanu The main tag is the same a a "div tag". It should structure your HTML. In this Code it is at the right place to use the "main tag" for the main content.
The second thing is that "href='#'" is completely correct and it should not be empty. That could lead to unexpected behaviour. But the element should be a "span" so that the "href tag" isn't necessary.

Comment: @MrWook That's what I updated the answer. If he must use the anchor tag then I've provided the way to do it else in general for such requirement span/button serves better. Added one more way which will avoid unexpected behaviour